# How Can I Display a MYSQL value into HTML div using PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel, web

I am working on a personal project (as a beginner). I am try to copy and paste a value from a MySQL table into a div (like age, class, etc) using `SESSION['username']` and `SESSION['age']` and so on but I soon realized that only the first one:  `SESSION['username']` worked because it was entered directly at the point of login.

How can I display a single value from a MySQL and have them pasted in various relevant divs, using PHP?

To clarify, if a div goes like `<div><strong> SMS Credit balance:</strong> [Credit balance goes here]</div>`

How can I do this with PHP please (in the homepage where the user is redirected to upon login)?

Here is what I did

```
<?php include(db-config.php);
session_start();
require_once __DIR__ . "/login.php";
$_SESSION['smsbalance'] = $result->mbalance;
$_SESSION['callbalance'] = $result->callbalance;
$_SESSION['avdbalance'] = $result->avbalance;
?>
```

Then I went to use: `<?php echo $_SESSION['smsbalance']?>` inside the various DIVs but they do not work.

I am a novice at this, please help. Thanks....

Comment: **Do not work** what does that really mean. Please be specific. Error messages? Or a description of what is happening and what you expected. Also seeing the code would be very useful

Comment: Are these DIV's in the same script or a different script

Comment: @RiggsFolly It doesn't show anything at all. Just an empty div.

Comment: @RiggsFolly let me paste the div themselves:

Comment: @RiggsFolly 
        ```<div style="float: left; width: 100%; text-align: center;">&nbsp;</div>
        <div style="float: left; width: 100%; text-align: left;">SMS Credit Balance：<strong><?php echo $_SESSION['smsbalance']?></strong>
        </div>
        <div style="float: left; width: 100%; text-align: left;">Call Credit Balance：<strong><?php echo $_SESSION['callbalance']?></strong>
        </div>
        <div style="float: left; width: 100%; text-align: center;">
          Account Available Balance：<strong><?php echo $_SESSION['avbalance']?></strong>
        </div>```

Comment: @ChibuikeEzeiru did you validate that your session variables actually contain values? Try to get to the root of the problem and check if the issue is in our $result object, or in passing session variables to the template